# $addField with subQuery in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections: Chargers and Reservation. I would like for the reservations in the next 7 days to be appended as a field when querying for chargers (i.e. time range from now until the same day next week).

The model for chargers looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"charger 2",
    "address":"test, test, USA",
    "current_type": 1,
    "charge_level" : 2,
    "plug_type" : 1,
}
```

and the reservation model looks like this:

```
{
  "charger_id": ObjectId("test ID"),
  "start_time": "31-01-2021",
  "end_time": "1-02-2021"
}
```

I found the aggregation $addField that adds a field within an aggregation pipeline, but I was wondering if I could use the $addfield on a "subquery". Essentiallly, for each charger that match, get all the reservations within a given time range where the chargerID is the one from the match, and add the array of reservations as a field. The resulting model would look like this:

```
{
    "name":"charger 2",
    "address":"test, test, USA",
    "current_type": 1,
    "charge_level" : 2,
    "plug_type" : 1,
    "reservations" : [
       ...
    ]
}
```

The current way of getting the data is with 2 queries at the application result, but that becomes quite taxing with the network latencies.

Query 1 - chargers:

```
{"_id":<charger_id>}
```

once I get the result, I query again.
Query 2 - Reservations:

```
{
"charger_id": <charger_id>,
"start_time" : {
   "$lte" : <date in a week>
   }
}
```

This is not too bad with a get by ID, because I already have the ID before querying for the charger in the first place, but with a *getAll*, or any other query that doesn't query by ID, it can get really taxing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "in the next 7 days"? Are you referring to a specific date range? Or you want to change your schema for the next 7 days... not sure I get that part.

Comment: Subquery of what? Can you add your initial query attempt? To have better understanding

Comment: Sure thing! Will make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring in data from another collection you need to use $lookup. $addFields can be used to add fields based on data you already have in the result set.